# Inject special characters symbol into the value attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, unicode, font-awesome

I am trying to inject a FontAwesome's unicode symbol into the `value` attribute of an `input` field.

The directive that I used is:

`$('.subscribeButton').attr("value", "&#xf105;");`

This, however, injects the literal string into the html.

How can I make the unicode symbol render as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#xf105;` - is for HTML. In java script it would be `\uf105`.

```
$('.subscribeButton').attr("value", "\uf105");
```